# Calculating a date from hour (1-8760)

Tags: vba, excel

I need to calculate a date from hour (1-8760). 
So for Index_hour=5535 and year= 2015 it should return 19/8@16:00 (19th August 4pm)
I have function but does not return what I need.

```
Public Function GetTimeString(Index As Integer) As String
    Dim aDate As Date
    aDate = DateAdd("h", Index, DateValue("Jan 01, 2015"))
    GetTimeString = CStr(Day(aDate)) & "/" & CStr(Month(aDate)) & "@" & CStr(Hour(aDate)) & ":00"
End Function
```

Comment: If you told us what it *does* return, maybe someone could spot the problem straight away...

Comment: I received -1 vote...what is wrong with my question? I do not understand.

Comment: See @AndrewMorton's comment.

Comment: What should it return for an input value of 1? I suspect that you might be counting your hours wrongly.

Comment: @AndrewMorton would be kind to give someone a chance. For h=1 is 01/01/2015 01:00:00

Comment: @mdengu FWIW, I didn't downvote - I was waiting for you to provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my approach.

```
debug.print dateserial(2015, 1, 1)+timeserial(5535, 0, 0)
```

However that resolves as 8/19/2015 3:00:00 PM. If you need 4:00 PM, add an additional hour to TimeSerial.

Both DateSerial and TimeSerial can accept any positive integer up to the maximum for a signed integer (32,767) for each of the parameters and correctly compute the date, time or datetime. e.g. `timeserial(32767, 32767, 32767)` is 10/19/1903 10:13:07 AM.

Comment: Must be a timezone or DST thing. Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: fwiw, both DateSerial and TimeSerial can accept any positive integer up to a maximum signed integer for each of the parameters and correctly compute the date, time or datetime. e.g. `timeserial(32767, 32767, 32767)` is 10/19/1903 10:13:07 AM.